# Why my broadcast is not received in this code?

Tags: android, receiver

Why my broadcast is not received in this code ?
I post my code below. When I run this, I can see sender broadcast intent.
But there is no response at receiver side.
I have tested on lollipop AVD.

- Receiver Manifest

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kr.co.company.mybroadcastreceiver" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="kr.co.company.START_WEB" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

- Receiver Code

  ```
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
          Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
          intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
          context.startActivity(intent1 );
      }
  }
  ```
- Sender Code

  ```
  public class MyBroadcastSender extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_broadcast_sender);

  Button click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
  click.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setAction("kr.co.company.START_WEB");
          sendBroadcast(intent);
      }
  });
  }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If another application is sending the intent, you should add this to the receiver definition in the manifest:

`android:exported="true"`